# Como colocar dois RecyclerView's dentro de uma Activity?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Gostaria de saber como faço para utilizar 2 `RecyclerView`'s dentro de uma mesma *activity*, de modo que uma fique ao lado da outra e que eu possa transportar dados entre elas?

Answer (score 1):

Vc pode montar dois recyclerview no XML,um do lado do outro,e então você na sua actvity criar o objeto de cada um e inicialos.entao você pode fazer a transferência de dados entre eles usando sharedpreferences ou o sqlite.

Comment: Como fazer isso? tem algum lugar que tenha exemplo?

Comment: Vou tentar montar um exemplo simples e coloco aqui